# warning C4819: How to find the character that has to be saved in unicode?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have seen the following warning recently through my VS2010.

Warning 21  warning C4819: The file contains a character that cannot be represented in the current code page (936). Save the file in Unicode format to prevent data loss

```
c:\boost\vs2010_boost1.49\include\boost\format\alt_sstream_impl.hpp 1
```

Based on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173715.aspx), the file contains a character that has to be saved in unicode format.

Question: I didn't touch those files myself. Is there a way that I can find those characters and correct it manually. In other words, I don't want to save the source file in unicode format.

Thank you

Comment: Copy and paste into notepad++ then change the encoding (Encoding menu) to the wanted codepage. Paste back.

Comment: You can save a copy as ANSI and compare with the original with your favourite file compare tool.

Comment: Do I have to recompile boost library? That will be tons of work since those files have to check-in.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to find all Unicode characters in a file using a regular expression:

1. Open your file in Notepad++.
2. Ensure that you select *UTF-8* from the *Encoding* menu.
3. Open the search box (use *CTRL-F* or go to the *Search* menu and select *Find...*).
4. Under Search Mode, select the radio button for *Regular expression*.
5. Enter `[^\x00-\x7F]` in the *Find what* box and hit the Find Next button to see what you get.

After you find the Unicode character(s), you can remove/change them, change the encoding back to ANSI, and save the file.

You don't have to use Notepad++, of course. The RegEx will work in other text editors, e.g., [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/3).

Comment: This was a big help tracking down a unicode issue in an asp file that I had to save.  Thank you!

Comment: Using the regex above with TextCrawler saved me having to do this with 1000 files.

Comment: Also, while using the Find dialog box in Notepad++, use the "Mark All" feature in the Mark tab.

Comment: if possible i would like to give double up-vote for this

Comment: You can also use this in VS

Comment: You just saved us several hours of digging. Thanks!

Comment: In my case it was because of word `isn’t` in a comment where `’` is unicode char.

Comment: @bob0the0mighty How?

Comment: Sorry @John, It's been nearly 6 years and I have no idea anymore.

Comment: @bob0the0mighty Thank you for your reply. I found the solution. The short-key is `ctrl+F`

Comment: Damn, I misunderstood your question. Yeah, ctrl-f will bring up the find input. shift+ctrl+f will bring up a more advanced find and replace menu that is easier to use if you're working over an entire solution.

Answer (score 8):

I met this problem in my project and tried to modify all non-unicode characters. But I had to give up and found a another way, as there were too many files with such problem (even though all of them are in comments).

Then I found a quick way to fix this by setting 'system locale'.

```
Control Panel -> Clock,Language,and Region -> Region and Language -> 
Administrative -> Language for non-Unicode programs -> Change system locale -> English
```

I think this could fix your problem if your 'system locale' is not English.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37871883/3148107

Comment: why would it be ok by setting locale to English? This file still contains a non-unicode char

Comment: I guess if locale is not English, non-unicode chars are decoded to some strange characters, which could not be recognized by the compiler.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the regex shown above in Visual Studio to locate those characters. Here is the Regex: `[^\x00-\x7F]`

Answer (score 2):

at line 176:

```c
BOOST_ASSERT(0); // §27.4.3.2 allows undefined-behaviour here
```

You see, there is a character before 27 in the above line.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you might have compiled a file which is encoded in another charset that is not the default charset of your operating system. One way is to delete those characters that can not decoded by your default encoding, but I prefer the other way which is just using Notepad++ to trans-coding your file. To achieve this goal, click **Encoding->Convert To xxx**, where xxx is your operating system default encoding.