# Theano + Windows + CUDA, work well using CMD, but encoutered error in eclipse (warning C4819)

Tags: python, eclipse, cmd, theano

I am working with `
Windows + CUDA 6.5 + VS2010 + Python2.7 + Theano. 
My Python scripts works well when using command line, say:

```
python DDI_convnet.py
```

and I get results as:

[image: passed in CMD 1]

[image: passed in CMD 2]

However, when I run the same `Python scripts` in `Eclipse`, I get a lot of errors:

[image: error in Eclipse 1]

[image: error in Eclipse 2]

[image: error in Eclipse 3]

I think this is probably due to the difference of character Map of `Eclipse` and `CMD`, because the `warning C4819` implies that a lot of `.h` files are not parsed correctly. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer myself. This is because, I installed Microsoft C++ for Python first, and then installed VS2010. The environment variable of Eclipse can only be updated after restarting windows.

However, after I restart windows, the problem changes, not  warning C4819 any more, it began to report errors like "unresolved external ...", which is mainly due to some DLLs or libs are not included correctly by Eclipse.

Finally, I decide to change my IDE to PyCharm. Everything goes well so far.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your system setting of 'system locale' is Chinese. Change it to English could possibly fix this problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37871883/3148107